# Are edits on the tag wiki for a tag used in both a meta site and Meta Stack Overflow preserved?

Tags: support, tag-wiki, per-site-meta, meta-faq

I am creating a little FAQ for *Drupal Answers* that would help the users who don't read Meta Stack Overflow, and that contains questions specific for the site (e.g. "Is it fine to cross post a question on Drupal.org, and *Drupal Answers*?").

As for the recent changes, the tag wiki for a meta site can be edited, and I was thinking to use that tag wiki to contain the list of the questions tagged *faq*.
As I remember, the tag wiki were previously pushed from Meta Stack Overflow to all the Stack Exchange 2.0 meta sites. What would happen in the case I edit the tag wiki for *Drupal Answers*, and that edit creates a conflict with the tag wiki existing on Meta Stack Overflow?